# Reverse geospatial search in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, geospatial

I have a collection of documents in mongodb where the each document has an attribute "viewport". "viewport" is a geoJSON object of type Polygon. the collection has 2dsphere index on the "viewport" attribute.

I would like to run a search where given a polygon, i want to **find all documents in the collection that fully contains the given polygon**.

I can't use $geoWithin because it does the opposite of what I am tring to do. So far the only solution I am able to find is to use $geoIntersects, and run separate process on each returned documenet to see which ones fully contain the provided polygon but this seems inefficient, especially when there are many documents that gets returned.

Is there a better way to do this?